# Node js - How to create an executable with pkg

Tags: node.js, express, zeit-pkg

I'm trying to create an `executable` in my node.js project with `pkg` and I can create this but without css files.

So, I install `pkg` with `npm install -g pkg`, in `package.json` I add this:

```
"pkg": {
    "scripts": "public/js/*.js",
    "assets": "public/css/*.css",
    "assets": "views/**/*"
  },
```

It adds the js.files fine and recognizes views, except css file.

My project structure is that:

- public

  - css

    - app.css
  - js

    - app.js
  - images
- views

---

In console, I ran the command `pkg .` and it generates linux, macos and win executables.

How can I add my css file and image folder too?

Comment: Can you try running `pkg package.json` and see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 1):

in package.json file add like this

```
 "pkg": {    
     "assets": [
         "views/*",
         "Public/**/*"    
      ],
  ...
  }
```

put all you images, js, css etc into Public folder

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have `pkg` detect assets in the source code rather than using a config object at the `package.json` level.

This is documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#detecting-assets-in-source-code). Basically, if you add the line `path.join(__dirname, '../path/to/asset.css');` to your source code `pkg` should automatically add it to the executable.

Comment: Where I add this? in index.js file? @dkimot

Comment: You could add it wherever. I would recommend adding it close to where assets would be used. If you have a server.js file whose purpose is to create a server that sends static assets, like your CSS and images, you could add the lines `path.join(__dirname, '../path/to/asset.css')` above the line that creates a static route. That way you don't need to read as much code to see where that's being required. Definitely, add comments as this is not really convention so people know why you are randomly joining a path.

Comment: Ok, I did it for .css and work fine. And for images folder inside public folder? I do this path.join(__dirname, '/public/images'); and don't work @dkimot

Comment: Try the same thing with a backslash at the end (`path.join(__dirname, '/public/images/');`

Comment: Okay, try adding the images as an asset to package.json. If that doesn't work, as an experiment can you try specifying an image file extension in the package.json to see what happens? Something like `"assets": "public/images/*.png"` just to see if that helps. Then we can work on getting all file types.